# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `0` supplied to `Image`

Tags: react-native

I was following **Multiplatform Mobile App Development with React Native** course at Coursera and in that course the instructor use a Card component. But I got warning when I exactly use the same code in my project.

```js
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `0` supplied to `Image`.
```

[here](https://pastebin.com/kZ5w8yXP) is the full warning message.
I think the following code causes the warning,

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';

function RenderDish(props) {
  const dish = props.dish;

  if (dish != null) {
    return (
      <Card
        featuredTitle={dish.name}
        image={require('./images/uthappizza.png')}
      >
        <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>{dish.description}</Text>
      </Card>
    );
  } else {
    return <View></View>;
  }
}
function Dishdetail(props) {
  return <RenderDish dish={props.dish} />;
}
export default Dishdetail;
```

But I didn't get why this warning was given? I didn't pass any prop which is related with style then why this occur? I heartily thank if anyone help me to figure out this.

---

As @Maycon Mesquita said, I tried `<Card style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }}>` as a prop in the `Card` but the warning is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Card />` component is passing an `array's element` as a `style's prop` to Image. This is wrong.

Try to set a width/height to `card`.

However, without knowing the card's code, i would try a generic style prop:

Option A: `style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }}`

Option B: `containerStyle={{ width: 150, height: 150 }}`

**Otherwise**, you will need to post the Card's component code, to we the Image prop's name.

Comment: The `Card` component is imported from `'react-native-elements'`.  @Maycon Mesquita

Comment: 3 days ago the Card got a commit named: 'Fix: Object getting created with key `0`'. I think this will solve your issue. But the maintainers should a release on npm.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/pull/2337

Comment: You can fork the current master branch or request release in this pull request page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking it was my fault.

Comment: No problem. Thanks!